# Rightfax set data on coversheet

Tags: rightfax

I am using rightfax web api to send fax. One of the requirement is to attach coversheet. I am able to attach coversheet using api and set some data like whom fax is sent to , company and email address. However i dont see option in Rightfax web api request to set fax data on coversheet like who has sent fax, his email id , phone number and notes . Can someone help. Below is documentation I am using

http://rightfaxsdk.cloudapp.net/RightFaxSdk/api/help

Answer (score 0):

The Web API considers the info like special tags.

```
        ActiveJob.Recipients.Add(new Recipient { Destination = FaxNumber, Name = ToName, Company = ToCompany, PhoneNumber = ToPhoneNum });

        ActiveJob.Tags.Add("Notes", Notes);
        ActiveJob.Tags.Add("BillingCode1", BillingCode1);

        ActiveJob.Tags.Add("BillingCode2", BillingCode2);
        ActiveJob.Tags.Add("FromName", From);
        ActiveJob.Tags.Add("FromVoiceNumber", FromVoiceNumber);
```